# make MySQL query choose max timestamp with group by statement

Tags: mysql

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
    log_timestamp, 
    system_name,
    faction_name,
    faction_allegiance, 
    faction_government_type, 
    current_state, 
    pending_state,
    recovering_state,
    influence AS influence,
    transactions.transaction_id
FROM `bgs`.`faction_log`
    INNER JOIN `factions` ON `factions`.`faction_id` = `faction_log`.`faction_id`
    INNER JOIN `transactions` ON `transactions`.`transaction_id` = `faction_log`.`transaction_id`
    INNER JOIN `system_log` ON `system_log`.`transaction_id` = `transactions`.`transaction_id`
    INNER JOIN `systems` ON `systems`.`system_id` = `transactions`.`associated_system_id` 
WHERE
    log_timestamp BETWEEN bgs.find_closest_tick_time(date('2017-08-14')) AND bgs.find_closest_tick_time(DATE_ADD(date('2017-08-14'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AND
    associated_system_id = 4 
GROUP BY 
    faction_name,
    log_timestamp,
    system_name,
    faction_allegiance, 
    faction_government_type, 
    current_state, 
    pending_state,
    recovering_state,
    influence,
    transactions.transaction_id
```

It works fine, and now looks like this:

`+---------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| log_timestamp       | system_name | faction_name    |
+---------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| 2017-08-14 11:18:46 | Nagii       | Nagii Autocracy |
| 2017-08-14 12:38:03 | Nagii       | Nagii Autocracy |
| 2017-08-14 13:40:18 | Nagii       | Nagii Autocracy |
| 2017-08-15 06:09:52 | Nagii       | Nagii Autocracy |
| 2017-08-14 11:18:46 | Nagii       | Nagii Network   |
| 2017-08-14 12:38:03 | Nagii       | Nagii Network   |
| 2017-08-14 13:40:18 | Nagii       | Nagii Network   |
| 2017-08-15 06:09:52 | Nagii       | Nagii Network   |
| 2017-08-14 11:18:46 | Nagii       | Nagii Posse     |
| 2017-08-14 12:38:03 | Nagii       | Nagii Posse     |
| 2017-08-14 13:40:18 | Nagii       | Nagii Posse     |
| 2017-08-15 06:09:52 | Nagii       | Nagii Posse     |
| 2017-08-14 11:18:46 | Nagii       | Nagii Union     |
| 2017-08-14 12:38:03 | Nagii       | Nagii Union     |
| 2017-08-14 13:40:18 | Nagii       | Nagii Union     |
| 2017-08-15 06:09:52 | Nagii       | Nagii Union     |
| 2017-08-14 11:18:46 | Nagii       | Nagii United Co |
| 2017-08-14 12:38:03 | Nagii       | Nagii United Co |
| 2017-08-14 13:40:18 | Nagii       | Nagii United Co |
| 2017-08-15 06:09:52 | Nagii       | Nagii United Co |
+---------------------+-------------+-----------------+
20 rows in set (0.00 sec)`

But i want to select only rows containing maximum value of field log_timestamp. (in this case 2017-08-15 06:09:52). I tried to use something like that:

`HAVING transactions.log_timestamp >= max(date('2017-08-15 06:09:52'));`

but it don't work like that:

`HAVING transactions.log_timestamp >= max(log_timestamp);`

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another solution. You don't need GROUP BY, if you just want one row per distinct value in all the columns of your select-list. You can do the same thing with `SELECT DISTINCT` as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    log_timestamp, 
    system_name,
    faction_name,
    faction_allegiance, 
    faction_government_type, 
    current_state, 
    pending_state,
    recovering_state,
    influence AS influence,
    transactions.transaction_id
FROM `bgs`.`faction_log`
    INNER JOIN `factions` ON `factions`.`faction_id` = `faction_log`.`faction_id`
    INNER JOIN `transactions` ON `transactions`.`transaction_id` = `faction_log`.`transaction_id`
    INNER JOIN `system_log` ON `system_log`.`transaction_id` = `transactions`.`transaction_id`
    INNER JOIN `systems` ON `systems`.`system_id` = `transactions`.`associated_system_id` 
WHERE
    log_timestamp BETWEEN bgs.find_closest_tick_time(date('2017-08-14')) AND bgs.find_closest_tick_time(DATE_ADD(date('2017-08-14'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AND
    associated_system_id = 4 
ORDER BY log_timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Since you just want the row with the max log_timestamp, you can sort by that column descending, and use LIMIT to return only the first row in the result.

Comment: The best for performance is to optimize the table(s) with indexes. You didn't post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for your tables, and I don't know which table `log_timestamp` belongs to, so I can't comment on which indexes would be needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a subquery, something like

```
WHERE
    log_timestamp = (
      SELECT MAX(log_timestamp) 
      FROM `bgs`.`faction_log`
      WHERE log_timestamp BETWEEN bgs.find_closest_tick_time(date('2017-08-14')) AND bgs.find_closest_tick_time(DATE_ADD(date('2017-08-14'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AND associated_system_id = 4
) AND associated_system_id = 4
```

Comment: Got syntax error, worked using this subquery in HAVING section and adding inner join of course =)

Comment: Thx for helping, Sebastian