# GROUP BY latlong Only If Within Same Date In SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Basically I am logging peoples actions when they visit my website.

I have logged people by the following:
id, page, pageid, pagetype, os, browser, device, referer, thed, longlat

Granted a lot of this information can easily be changed but in most cases it will be ok.

Anyway while I am doing the backend I have ran into a problem with my sql query.

Basically this is what I want it to do:

```
//thed is the date EXAMPLE: 2017-08-28 01:20:28
os, browser, device, referer, longlat FROM visitors WHERE thed > :thed
```

But I also want to GROUP BY the longlat but only foreach day that arises from the database.

So if the date is 2017-08-27 then group by longlat for that day, and again if the day was 2017-08-28 then group by longlat for that day... So on and so on...

Is there a way through SQL rather than build a few multi arrays to combat this?

Thanks

Comment: You know that you can group by more than one criterion, right …?

Comment: @CBroe yes I am aware, but I am not aware how and I have searched all day to find how to search only on each day of a every date given.

Comment: You can look there, i think it's what you need: [similar answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45919711/make-mysql-query-choose-max-timestamp-with-group-by-statement/45919799#45919799)

Comment: And your research on how to get only the date portion of a datetime column has turned up what?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
.. WHERE thed > :thed
GROUP BY DATE(thed), longlat
```